# Getting InfluxDB Error: error parsing query

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb

I am trying to capture the real time data from Jmeter in InfluxDB and showing that in GRAFANA. I used the online resources for this. But I am getting the below mentioned error.

```
message:"InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: found (, expected identifier at line 1, char 39"
data:Object
error:"error parsing query: found (, expected identifier at line 1, char 39"
message:"error parsing query: found (, expected identifier at line 1, char 39"
config:Object
method:"GET"
url:"api/datasources/proxy/1/query"
params:Object
data:null
precision:"ms"
inspect:Object
paramSerializer:serializeParams(e){…}
headers:Object
retry:0
hideFromInspector:false
```

Can someone please help me, why I am getting this error and how could I fix this?

Comment: What is your request? Show link to resource

Answer (score 2):

If you're using "online resources" you should ask the question there as we're not telepathic enough to guess what you're trying to implement.

The official "online resources" are:

- [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener)
- [Real-time Results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#realtime-results)

Community "online resources"

- [JMeter + Grafana: How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana) - for InfluxDB 1.x
- [JMeter InfluxDB v2.0 listener plugin](https://github.com/mderevyankoaqa/jmeter-influxdb2-listener-plugin) - for InfluxDB 2.x